# How can I group by date starting at a different time than midnight?

Tags: sql

I'd like to do it in one statement if possible.

My original query was this:

```
SELECT CAST(Date as DATE) as DayDate, SUM(Books) as LostBooks 
FROM RestartBooksView 
WHERE Name = 'AUHT167' and Date > (getdate() - 105) 
GROUP BY CAST(Date as DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(Date as DATE) ASC
```

The problem with this query is that I want the summations to be reflected by a 7 AM to 7 AM day rather than the 12 AM to 12 AM day currently. How can I modify my query to reflect this change?

Comment: Perhaps also consider more concise title for your question.

Comment: Perhaps also consider changing your username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the column "date" is really a datetime.

```
SELECT CAST(Date as DATE) as DayDate, SUM(Books) as LostBooks
FROM (select rbv.*,
             cast(dateadd(h, -7, date) as date) as newdate
      from RestartBooksView rbv
     )
WHERE Name = 'AUHT167' and newdate > (getdate() - 105)
GROUP BY newdate
ORDER BY CAST(Date as DATE) ASC
```

I also used SQL Server date functions, since you seem to be using that database.